# Linqを使用してListのなかのListがもつ値にアクセスしたい

Tags: c#, linq

以下の様なListのなかにListをもつものから、foreachなどを使用せずにLinqで内側のListの要素にIEnumerableでアクセスする方法はありませんか？

```
var root = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> inner = null;
     for (var i = 1 ; i <= 11; i++){
          inner = new List<int>();
          inner.Add(i);
          root.Add(inner);
     } 
//IEnumerable<int>でアクセスしたいが、IEnumerable<List<int>>となってしまう
var number = from n in root select n;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<int> number = from n in root
                          from m in n
                          select m;
```

とか

```
IEnumerable<int> number = root.SelectMany(n => n);
```

とかでアクセスできます。

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で解決できました！ありがとうございました

Answer (score 0):

アクセスしてどうしたいのかがわかりませんが、Select内でSelectすればいいのではないでしょうか？

root.Select(x=> x.Select(y=> y ));

Comment: 質問の仕方が良くなかったようです、次回はどういうふうに結果を利用するかも記述します　ご解答ありがとうございました